# Я хочу написать проверку для авторизации

Tags: php, mysql, auth

Я хочу создать авторизацию и регистрацию для своего сайта. Что бы потом подключить его к моему лаунчеру майнкрафта (авторизация). Но проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сделать отдельный файл для проверки логина и пароля. И если вы неправильно или правильно ввели логин и пароль (в лаунчере) - был определенный отклик с сайта.
Типа:"Login or password correct/incorrect"

Comment: Почему метка php? У вас сервис авторизации на php? Если да то у вас должен быть механизм отправки логина и пароля в ваш сервис? Да? Тогда гуглите "авторизация/регистрация юзеров на php"

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать API с авторизацией. Например Laravel Passport
https://si-dev.com/ru/blog/rest-api-auth-with-laravel-passport